# Can someone give an example solution to what this function is supposed to do?

Tags: python, dictionary, graph

Basically, I understand what the code is supposed to do but not sure what it means by a dictionary mapping a URL to a list of target URLs. Can someone perhaps give an example of this?

```
WEB_DATA = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'school_web.txt')

def load_graph(fd):
    """Load graph from text file

    Parameters:
    fd -- a file like object that contains lines of URL pairs

    Returns:
    A dict mapping a URL (str) to a list of target URLs (str).
    """

    # Iterate through the file line by line
    for line in fd:
        # And split each line into two URLs
        node, target = line.split()
        raise RuntimeError("This function is not implemented yet.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine a dictionary mapping a url to a list of urls is something like

```
{ 'https://google.com': ['https://example.com', 'https://stackoverflow.com'],
  'https://duckduckgo.com': ['https://twitter.com'] }
```

Would that make sense?

---

Do you realise that that function always returns a `RuntimeError` complaining of something that should really be `NotImplementedError`.

Answer (score 0):

The input parameter is a file descriptor that is opened for a file that contains lines of urls separated by some whitespacing

```
url1 url2 
url1 url3
url2 url3
```

Assumably, you group together each url in the first column and build a list of outgoing targets